# Sumproduct check if text is name of a named range and return those numbers

Tags: excel, sum, formula, calculation, sumproduct

the user is able to enter either a number or a name into a cell. When i put a number, sumproduct is working fine, but when i want it to check if the name of a named range is inside the cell, it doesn't return anything.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!A:A=A7)*((Data!C:C=V7)+(Data!C:C=W7)),Data!H:H)
```

`Data!A:A` is an accountnumber and `Data!C:C` is the countryID. `Data!H:H` is the sales that need to be added up.

I have a few named ranges with number attached to them

- FirstRange: 4, 12, 15
- SecondRange: 7, 38, 65

How can I check inside my sumproduct if the cell has a named range and then apply that named range array to be summed up?

[image]

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve - what do you mean by "check if the cell has a named range"? Could you please paste some screenshots to help us understand?

Comment: I've added a picture to the question. Hopefully that makes it a bit clearer. In column B you can add the countryID or should be able to put one of the named ranges on the right

Comment: Thanks, I think it is a little bit clearer. Let me post an answer and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you currently have two named ranges:

[image]

As per your screenshot, it looks like you are looking for this Array formula (enter it with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($M$2:$M$13=A2),--IF(ISNUMBER(B2),($N$2:$N$13=B2),ISNUMBER(MATCH($N$2:$N$13,INDIRECT(B2),0))),$O$2:$O$13)
```

See the results below - I have added a color-coding in column `A` and columns `P-S` to show how the formula works (i.e. which rows are being included / excluded into the `SUMPRODUCT` calculation):

[image]

Comment: Hm... not exactly. I have added part of my database into the same sheet *see screenshot update in post*. It needs to check there what country ID fit with the accounts and then sum all the amounts together.

Comment: Ahh I see now - thanks for explaining. I'll adjust my answer now.

Comment: My god that worked. Also the Ctrl+Shift+Enter was something I had not thought of. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you and that you discovered something new :) take care