# SUMPRODUCT with multiple criteria while ignoring blank input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calculation, sumproduct, nonblank

There is currently a nice check for if the account and country id match then get the amount and sum. Now I have another account, which I want to leave empty in the B column since it includes all the country ids. How do I let sumproduct ignore the criteria is the field is empty, or accept everything as correct?

See below the solution that was presented in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681314/sumproduct-check-if-text-is-name-of-a-named-range-and-return-those-numbers) by Justyna MK.

[image]

I've tried to use NOT(ISBLANK( or using an IF(ISBLANK(B4), but i don't know what it should return if it is indeed blank.

**DESIRED OUTCOME:**
If for example column B4 is empty instead of having 8 as value, i want the sum to be 91. Same for B5, which should then be 172 insstead of 155.

Comment: any link to your "previous question" ?

Comment: Include a `IF()` statement to check if cell is empty?

Comment: I've added the link to the previous question in the post. I want to avoid IF() as often as possible

Comment: Then what have you tried yourself to avoid it? Can you include: what you have tried, what your current result shows and what your desired result looks like?

Comment: Can you simplify your question. Just what is input data? What is output? How the output coming? It seems not so complex to achieve.

Comment: you want to calculate the total amount in Column O: O by Acount number? maybe:
=SUMPRODUCT(($M$2:$M$13=A2)*(O2:O13)), or I am misunderstanding the question. because it's really unclear.

Comment: I've added a few more lines. I do hope this will make it a bit more clear.

Comment: As per my other comment, just a simple `IF` will do. Why would you avoid it? `IF(B4="",SUMIF(<criteriarange>,<criteria>,<sumrange>),<restofyourformula>)`?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I might want to add more criteria later that will also be able to be left empty. So that would mean having more and more if statements. Or would that not make a huge difference besides just a longer line of formula?

Comment: Can't you just use `SUMIFS()` ? (with an 'S' at end)

Answer (score 0):

I would try write a non-volatile formula, maybe like so:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUM(IF(B2="",SUMIF(M$2:M$13,A2;O$2:O$13),IF(ISNUMBER(B2),SUMIFS(O$2:O$13,M$2:M$13,A2;N$2:N$13;B2),SUMIFS(O$2:O$13,M$2:M$13;A2,N$2:N$13,CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"EUROPE","BENELUX"},0),Europe,Benelux)))))
```

Entered as `CSE` (which btw removes the need for `SUMPRODUCT`).

I'm not sure why you would still try to avoid `IF`, since it actually can give *clarity* to users of what's going on, and it avoids *unnecessary* heavy calculation.

---

***EDIT:*** Hereby also a scenario where you would have a third named ranged holding **all** country codes (currently the same as "EUROPE"):

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B2),SUMIFS(O$2:O$13,M$2:M$13,A2;N$2:N$13,B2),SUMIFS(O$2:O$13,M$2:M$13,A2,N$2:N$13,CHOOSE(MATCH(B2,{"EUROPE","BENELUX",0},0),Europe,Benelux,ALL))))
```

Also entered as `CSE`.

This would remove the need for the first check for empty with `IF` and the first `SUMIF`. Instead it matches the empty cell (which returns the value `0`) against a provided list and chooses the appropriate named range.

Comment: Perhaps  I should indeed use IF. I just always thought it slowed down the calculations. But I might be wrong there.

Comment: Go with whatever way you feel is right. I'm just posting this as what I see as a good approach. @Worempie.